# shellexecuteEx with multiple parameters

Tags: c, windows, winapi, sdk

I want to call `dpinst.exe /u .\\foldername\\foldername\\inffile.inf \d` using `shellexecuteEX`. How to do this. Sorry I am confused with multiple parameters. and I tried the below code which is not working.

```
hExecInfo.lpParameters = TEXT ("/u .\\dist\\Driver\\inffile.inf /d");
ShExecInfo.lpFile = TEXT (".\\dist\\dpinstx86.exe");
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Does it work with one or no parameters?

Comment: What is the value of `GetLastError()` after the call to `ShellExecuteEx()`?

Comment: @chris yes it works with one parameter. My doubt is with multi parameters.? the executable works fine but the expected result differs.

Comment: @hmjd Its workking actually my doubt here is the code snippet right? because its not giving me the expected result.

Comment: The `lpParameters` must include the EXE file path you want to execute as if it was typed from a CMD prompt.

Comment: @Jay No its not working the way you say.

Comment: @user1317084: Make sure you're in the correct working path since all specified paths are relative. You'll also need to check the returned error code so you'll know what exactly wasn't working. If it returns no error, it means that `ShellExecuteEx` **do** work. If the process exit code is also zero, then the culprit is most likely that the *INF* file wasn't made correctly.

Answer (score 1):

An omission from the posted is the setting of the [`cbSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) member:

```
shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(shExecInfo);
```

This is required (and is very common with other WINAPI functions that accept `struct`s).

Comment: I was thinking that, hence my comment. I guess we'll eventually see if it's right.

Comment: I assigned cbsize. Even after that am not getting the expected result. the problem is with passing multiple parameters to the exe.

Answer (score 1):

When executing .exe files, you really should be using `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute/Ex()`, eg:

```
STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFO), 0};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

TCHAR szCmdLine[] = TEXT(".\\dist\\dpinstx86.exe /u .\\foldername\\foldername\\inffile.inf \d");

if (CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```